# Alternative to G-MScreen in Windows

Tags: windows, android, ios

I am looking for G-MScreen windows alternative to achieve this goal, with the following features:

- Can let me watch channels from STB on my windows laptop, preferably windows 7.
- Can allow me to search/switch STB channels from windows PC, over same wifi connection.

G-MScreen works nice on my mobile but i'm not an avid mobile user and would like if there is a similar alternative for windows, which will be actually better to watch channels on a bigger screen and control them more easily. The following are some details for G-MScreen app.

G-MScreen is a client app for STB (Set Top Box), it works with STB through internet. (CRYPTODROID and Cryptobox). It allows to watch channels from STB on mobile device over same wifi connection. And it allows to Search/Switch STB channels as well as edit channels, move, rename, delete, lock, set favorite, sort etc and it works like virtual remote control. It can also check channels EPG (Electronic Program Guide) and change the setting of STB like sleep timer, parental control, password, screen lock/unlock, power on/off, factory default. It works with my Starsat SR-2000HD hyper dish tv receiver and other STB's.

Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mktvsmart.screen&hl=en

iOS: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/g-mscreen-multiple-screen/id921933799

Comment: Thanks.. i edited my question earlier today and hopefully its okay now. let me know if there is anything else i can do to improve it more.

Comment: i have been searching for this since several months and even posted a question on superuser few months ago which got deleted due to wrong place and finally decided to post again on softwarerecs.. but It seems not a single windows alternative exists.. While i think G-MScreen is quite unique app that even android have no other alternative.. I guess props to developer.. But i still hope there is an alternative for windows.

Comment: Any android emulator like bluestacks would work. There isnt anything that can run on windows natively.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround solution to watch GM-Screen compatible STB (set top box) content on a Windows PC
** Only tested on SuperMax SM2425 STB, the details may be different for other STB models (eg. stream names) **

Requirements

1. A recent version of VLC installed your PC
2. GM-Screen and VLC apps installed on your Phone
3. PC, Phone and STB (set top box) on the same local area network

Steps on STB

1. Join the local area network (or wifi) and take note of the STB ip address (eg. 192.168.0.101)

Steps on Phone

1. Login to your STB via GM-Screen app (you should see a list of channels when you do).
2. Press the "..." button in the menu at the bottom of the screen (shows additional menu items).
3. Press "My Setting", it is the last item so scroll sideways if it is hidden.
4. Select "Player setting" (shows list of video apps, with "Built-in player" on top).
5. Choose VLC and go back to the channel list.
6. Press "..." beside the channel name (shows submenu below channel name, with Play item).
7. Press "Play" and wait until it starts playing in VLC.
8. Press the screen to show the controls, find the channel stream name near the top center.
9. Take note of the channel stream name (should be similar to "player.4655194" with different number).

Steps on PC

1. Go to your desktop or any folder on your PC and right click an empty space to get a context menu.
2. Select/Hover over the "New" menu item (submenu should appear), then select "Shortcut" near the top (shows a prompt to enter location).
3. Type or paste the following including quotes: "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "http://192.168.0.101:8085/player.4655194" --deinterlace=-1
4. Optional: If you have a different installation directory for vlc, replace the first part (eg. "Program Files (x86)" is only on 64-bit windows).
5. Optional: You can also have different options for vlc instead of "--deinterlace=-1", or remove it entirely.
6. Replace "192.168.0.101" with the STB ip address and "player.4655194" with the channel stream name you noted in previous steps.
7. Select "Next" button (shows a prompt for shortcut name) and enter the channel name (The shortcut should be created).
8. Double click the shortcut to run VLC (The channel video stream should play on your PC).

Notes

1. It is possible to change the "Player setting" in GM-Screen back to "Built-in player" once you have noted the channel stream name.
2. You must start playing the channel stream on your phone in GM-Screen before you can play it via the shortcut on your PC.
3. There is a different stream name for each channel, so you must have a shortcut for each channel.
4. You can only change channels on your phone in GM-Screen, and must use a shortcut on the PC everytime the channel changes.
5. If somebody else uses the remote of the STB to change channels, the stream stops and you have to use a shortcut to see the changed channel on your PC.
6. This workaround was tested with a SuperMax SM2425 STB, VLC (2.2.1) on Windows 10, and the latest versions of VLC (2.0.6) and GM-Screen (1.0.2744) for android in March 2017.

Obviously this is not an ideal use case scenario and everyone would prefer to use a PC app, but this is as far as I got with it.

Comment: Thanks for showing a work around. So its difficult but possible, again thanks to G-MScreen.

Comment: Can you paste this method in pastebin and share a link at the end? that would be easier for me and others to create a shortcut without any mistake.

I'm trying to check stream name in VLC Player but when i press screen, its showing "G-MScreen.ts" name in top middle on screen. Nothing like player.323214 something. I'm also using latest versions of both apps. G-MScreen v1.0.2744 and VLC v2.0.6

Comment: @Ali, have you tried using "G-MScreen.ts" as the stream name in the PC shortcut in the place of "player.323214"? There seems to be differences between STB models, so you might have to figure out what works on yours by trial and error - if you have the time & energy :)

Comment: I tried this but its not working. This is the error. http://prntscr.com/el85nz
Is it possible it could be issue with port. 8085.. how do you define this port? if its related to STB, then it might be different on StartSat SR 2000.

Comment: Can you ping 192.168.1.2 from cmd (command prompt) on windows? Also see if you can telnet into the STB, via a tool like Putty. If that is possible then you can run commands to show all open ports, I found the port by that means.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I just tried to ping and that's working fine. I tried to telnet into STB via default 23 and 8085 port and it close Putty immediately. Tried SSH with 22 and that's giving error. Any other suggestion to find port or connecting via telnet? is it possible to find port directly in stb settings? I tried to search ports for this STB but nothing useful came out.